# how to read a textfile with python gevent

Tags: python, nginx, gevent, pymysql

I have tried to  read a `nginx` log file with python, but the log file is too big.

Can I read the file by `gevent`?

**BTW , The log file has one million lines**
Can I  store the data into `mysql`with `pysqml` api?

Comment: What prevents you from just reading the file row by row and inserting as you read?

Comment: BTW, Why do no store the log into the `ElasticSearch` instead of `MySQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my comment as an answer just to illustrate what I mean: why not just read the file line by line and insert the data as you go?

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=####, user='userid', passwd='password', db='db')
cursor = cur = conn.cursor()
insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO logs (param1, param2, param3...) VALUES (%s, %s, %s...)"
with open('logfile.log', 'r') as log:
    for row in log:
        cursor.execute(insert_cmd, tuple(row))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: because of take too long time

Comment: And you think that `[insert whatever library you are planning to use]` can read the file faster?

Comment: Well then you could read the file and write it into e.g. a suitable csv format and use `LOAD DATA INFILE` using mysql tools directly.